# Blank window after cropping an image

Tags: python, opencv

I have written a code to crop and image and display on screen. Unfortunately I am getting a blank window after cropping. Any suggestions?

```
import cv
image_raw = cv.imread('ball.png')         #read the image
cv.ShowImage('image_raw',image_raw)       #show the image
rec = (180,300,250,180)                   #rectangle defining roi
image = cv.SetImageROI(tagged_image,rec)  #for selecting roi from an image
cv.ShowImage('image',image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your version of Python but there is a very clear and basic discussion of this with examples at:  http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0202/

I also know from past experience that some images have a minimum size and if you crop beyond that you will end up with no image.

The best approach to cropping images using Python involves using Pillow which the site above assumes.

The home site for Pillow is at:  https://python-pillow.org/ and there is plenty of help there as well.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, it was in visualizing only, try to write the image to disk and open it with image viewer.